# PHP: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I know there are a lot of these questions concerning this error, but neither of the answers all over stack overflow, google etc. helped me with my problem. Maybe someone here can figure out, why this error constantly occures. 
I am relatively new to PHP, so for little Applications I read a lot of tutorials and use them for my cases.

I tried to do a registration page using the following tutorial: http://www.codingcage.com/2015/11/ajax-registration-script-using-jquery-php.html

After everything isset and done, I always get the Error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 !

...when I submit the registration. So I think it has to be in this part of the code:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM geraeteuser WHERE `user_email` LIKE :email";
$stmt = $db_con->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$user_email));
```

I tried everything using backtips here and there, but no matter what I do, it doesn't work.

The full Code looks like this ("geraetestatus" is the table name):

```
<?php

require_once "dbconfig.php";

if($_POST)
{
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_password = $_POST['password'];

    $password = md5($user_password);

    try
    {   
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM geraeteuser WHERE `user_email` LIKE :email";
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare($qry);
        $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$user_email));
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($count==0){

        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO `geraeteuser`(user_name,user_email,user_password) VALUES(:uname, :email, :pass");
        $stmt->bindParam(":uname",$user_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email",$user_email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pass",$password);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "registered";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Query could not execute !";
            }

        }
        else{

            echo "1"; //  not available
        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}?>
```

and in the File "dbconfig.php", that is included, there is a pdo created like this:

```
<?php

$db_host = ***;
$db_name = ***;
$db_user = ***;
$db_pass = ***;

try{

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name";

    $db_con = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to make this work? I tried nearly everything I could find here and in the google answers, but nothing helped.

Comment: Which sql statement generates the error?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I think, it always occures when I fill out the form and submit it, so it has to be this one, I suppose 

`$qry = "SELECT * FROM geraeteuser WHERE 'user_email' LIKE :email";
$stmt = $db_con->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$user_email));`

Comment: @SilvioHungsberg Did you actually use singlequotes in the query, or wasit just because of the formatting on SO comments using backticks too? And how do you know that its the SELECT query, and not the INSERT one?

Comment: It was because of formatting. Now I edited the startpost. Thanks for that so far.

I don't know exactly, where the error occures. Its just a guess. Can you give me some advice, how I can figure that out exactly?

Comment: Like I asked above, how do you know for sure that its the SELECT query which generates this error, and not the INSERT one? You need to figure that out first, you can for example do that by wrapping each query in its own try/catch block, and print which query it is. Also, can you show the relevant code for the AJAX call?

Comment: Oh my god, I tried nearly everything yesterday to figure out, why the SELECT didn't work. Now you guys made me looking for errors in the other parts of the code and I found my mistake: At the end of the "INSERT"-Line there is a ")" missing...how dumb. Thank you all, I think I should have made a pause yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Insert query String is a Missing closing bracket at the end.
You neee to Close VALUES( ... --> ) <--

Comment: Already figured that out like posted above, but thank you very much for your help :)